# Remove duplicate items from second list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists with few duplicate items. I want to remove these duplicate items from the `list2`.

```
List<String> list1 = new List<String>() { John, Donald, White, Trump, Bill };
List<String> list2 = new List<String>() { Michael, Donald, Trump, Jerry, Obi };
```

Hence, the result will be:

```
list2 = Michael, Jerry, Obi
```

Any help is appreciated.

Note: I DON'T want to merge list1 and list2 items.

Comment: Use the [Enumerable.Except()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-5.0) method.

Comment: `list2.RemoveAll(list1.Contains);`

Comment: Please try to make some effort when asking a question. For instance, your strings are not quoted, so they will be evaluated as undefined variables, causing a compile error. Please also show any research you've done and any attempts you've made based on that research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In place:

```
list2.RemoveAll(list1.Contains);
```

As a copy:

```
var list3 = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```

Comment: Which one shall be faster?

Comment: @NewYorker benchmark them and you will find out. [find it on github](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)

Comment: When choosing it's important to know that `list2.RemoveAll()` will modify `list2`, while `list2.Except().ToList()` leave `list2` untouched, but also create a new list.

Comment: @NewYorker Focus on semantics rather than speed; do you want a new instance or not?

Comment: @Sinatr from the post: `list2 = Michael, Jerry, Obi` it seems that the removal of items from list2 is actually what OP wants

Comment: If you want speed, use `HashSet<T>`.